# where is the vim executable in vim-7.3.tar.bz2

Tags: vim

I downloaded vim-7.3.tar.bz2, which is said containing source and runtime. I unpacked it but I cannot find the executable for vim program. Where is it?

Comment: You downloaded the source code, not an executable.

Comment: Is there a executable to download? I do not want to make install that because there is an old version of vim in the server. I just want to use the new version myself without affecting others,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual steps are:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/username
$ make
$ make install
```

There are many ways to customize the whole process, you should do `$ ./configure --help` before anything to have an idea of what you can do.

1. The first step is where you define all the options used for building. `$ ./configure` without options just uses the default settings.
2. The second step is the building itself.
3. The last step is where the executable is moved to the path given at configuration time, `/home/username/bin/vim` in my example.

Another solution is to simply do `$ make`, move the executable where you want and make sure this location belongs to your path `or` create an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Open source packages seldomly contain both sources and binaries, especially because Vim runs on so many different platforms.

Binary downloads are listed at http://www.vim.org/download.php

You didn't tell the operating system you're on; for Windows, the Cream project (http://cream.sourceforge.net/) provides up-to-date packages and installers; for Linux, it's best to rely on the distribution's package management.

To have a local user (vs. system / root) -install, you either have to hack around the package management (cp. https://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory), or compile (with a custom install prefix) from the sources (which you have already downloaded!)

If you want to follow the latest and greatest Vim and continually update, check out its Mercurial repository and compile Vim from there.

Comment: I am on Redhat Enterprise 4. How to compile install vim without affecting existing old version vim on the server?

Comment: Basically, this is running `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local; make; make install` (last one without using `sudo`); this is pretty standard stuff (though I didn't do this on my own yet).

Answer (score 0):

Open your old version vim and then type:

```
:help install
```

You'll find everything you need there. There is even a section on installing in your home:

```
:help install-home
```